# RedCloth escaping HTML output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, markup, redcloth

After watching [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages), I thought I'd give [RedCloth](https://github.com/jgarber/redcloth) a try.  Unfortunately, it looks like I'm having an issue that involves the resultant HTML being encodeded instead of rendered as straight HTML.

1. First I added the following to my Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.7'
   ```
2. I added a basic RedCloth implementation to my view:

   ```
   <%= RedCloth.new("* one\n* two\n * three").to_html %>
   ```
3. When I "view source" for the page that is rendered, this is what appears:

   ```
   &lt;ul&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;one&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;two&lt;/li&gt;
       &lt;li&gt;three&lt;/li&gt;
   &lt;/ul&gt;
   ```

   The output I expected was the following:

   ```
   <ul>
       <li>one</li>
       <li>two</li>
       <li>three</li>
   </ul>
   ```

   Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to pass a parameter to `to_html` or the RedCloth constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= raw RedCloth.new("* one\n* two\n * three").to_html %>
```

Also check out [this blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) on the subject.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick!  Thanks for the informative link as well...I just started toying with Rails 3 (vs. 2.3.x), and I haven't yet read up on all the changes introduced.